# Showing all VCS actions in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: version-control, intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA has a shortcut (`Alt+BackQuote`) for VCS operations. However, it only shows some operations (e.g. no Update Project, Fetch, Pull). Is it possible to show all operations there or change which operations are shown?

Comment: Should be possible by a plugin, if it's something you want really bad :) Otherwise, can't you just use / define keystrokes for the other things you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly change that particular Quick List, but you can define your own. You can then map it to a Keyboard shortcut, either a different one or to the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backquote</kbd>. The one down side is that for a number of actions you can only define actions specific to a particualr VCS. The built in QuickList puts in actions for the specific VCS defined in the Project settings. A manually defined QuickList will not have that logic/ability. That's not a problem if you always use the same version control system. But if you switch between VCSes for different projects, it means needing multiple Quick Lists. A Quick List can contain other Quick Lists. So you can put all the common items (e.g. Update Project) in a list along with sub Quick Lists to VCS specific actions (e.g. rollback for CVS, revert for SVN, etc) if you do use multiple version control systems.

To create a Quick List, go to *File > Settings > [IDE Settings] > Quick Lists*. Click the Add icon and add the desired actions (VCS actions are under *Main Menu > VCS*). Once you have it created, you can map a shortcut under *File > Settings > [IDE Settings] > Keymaps > Quick Lists*. (You may need to close and reopen the setting dialog before the new Quick List shows in the Keymaps).

Another option would be to record a macro (*Edit > Macros*) to open the VCS menu and map it to a keyboard shortcut. Regardless of the version control system the project uses, It is the ninth menu item in the VCS menu. (The only exception is if a project has multiple version control systems defined, then it will be 9, 10, etc.) So if you record a macro with the sequence:

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
2. <kbd>↓</kbd> 9 times
3. <kbd>→</kbd>

...that will open the VCS menu with all the options.